# cron task four hour later

Tags: debian, cron

I have this task in my crontab

```
0 14 * * * command
```

but in my /var/log/syslog, I have

```
Jun 21 19:00:01 debian-squeeze-base /USR/SBIN/CRON[12810]: (user) CMD (command)
```

why the task run 5 hours later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves me correctly, you have to restart the cron daemon after changing your timezone.

Have you changed your timezone since your last reboot?

Answer (score 1):

How is your locale set?  How is your timezone set?

Perhaps the user running the cron (root) is using something in UTC and you are expecting it in localtime?

Comment: `# cat /etc/timezone 
America/Santiago`